# scroll a div automatically when a child is at the top / bottom borders

Tags: jquery

My code works, but it would be better to scroll `parent` automatically when `titleact` comes to the bottom / top of its parent, so it would be always visible.

I tried various ways with `offset`, `position` and `scrollTop` without success.

```js
$('.btnup').click(function() {
  let i = $('.titleact').index('.title');
  if (i == 0) {
    return;
  }
  let targ = $('.title').eq(i - 1);
  $('.titleact').insertBefore(targ);
});

$('.btndown').click(function() {
  let i = $('.titleact').index('.title');
  let count = $('.title').length;
  if (i == count - 1) {
    return;
  }
  let targ = $('.title').eq(i + 1);
  $('.titleact').insertAfter(targ);
});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 250px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: lightblue;
}

.title {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 9px;
  line-height: 23px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.titleact {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent'>
  <div class='title titleact'>title 01</div>
  <div class='title'>title 02</div>
  <div class='title'>title 03</div>
  <div class='title'>title 04</div>
  <div class='title'>title 05</div>
  <div class='title'>title 06</div>
  <div class='title'>title 07</div>
  <div class='title'>title 08</div>
  <div class='title'>title 09</div>
  <div class='title'>title 10</div>
</div>
<br>
<button class='btnup'>UP</button>
<button class='btndown'>DOWN</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply `scrollTop` animate function to `$(".parent")` on current position of `$(".titleact")`

Check below code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.btnup').click(function () {
        let i = $('.titleact').index('.title');
        if (i == 0) {
            return;
        }
        let targ = $('.title').eq(i - 1);
        $('.titleact').insertBefore(targ);
        scrollFunc();
    });

    $('.btndown').click(function () {
        let i = $('.titleact').index('.title');
        let count = $('.title').length;
        if (i == count - 1) {
            return;
        }
        let targ = $('.title').eq(i + 1);
        $('.titleact').insertAfter(targ);

        scrollFunc();
    });
});

function scrollFunc() {
    $(".parent").animate({ scrollTop: $(".parent").scrollTop() + $('.titleact').offset().top - 10 }, 'slow');
};
```

```css
.parent {
    width: 250px;
    height: 120px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: lightblue;
}

.title {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 9px;
    line-height: 23px;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.titleact {
    background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent'>
    <div class='title titleact'>title 01</div>
    <div class='title'>title 02</div>
    <div class='title'>title 03</div>
    <div class='title'>title 04</div>
    <div class='title'>title 05</div>
    <div class='title'>title 06</div>
    <div class='title'>title 07</div>
    <div class='title'>title 08</div>
    <div class='title'>title 09</div>
    <div class='title'>title 10</div>
</div>
<br>
<button class='btnup'>UP</button>
<button class='btndown'>DOWN</button>
```

Comment: it works but it should not scroll untill child is at the bottom. And when scrolling maybe to scroll entire parent height so current child is again at the top.